# Query for reporting through SQL Server DB 'dd/MMM/yyyy' from windows application issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, windows, datetime

this might be a silly question for most of you but i need serious help here,

I've one application in which reporting is needed
I am storing date in SQL Server DB in two columns as '`dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`' format(screen shot attached) the column data type is `nvarchar(50)`. Now whenever i try to select the range from the front end and try to generate the result it is not giving me any records or not proper records, maybe it is not comparing it properly or i am making any mistakes.
[Please check this image for DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jPe9.jpg)

Please check the below query where i wanted to generate records from 01 Nov 2016 to 01 DEC 2016, it gave me no records, and i checked that records are present in DB.

```
select * from WEIGHT where Odate between '01-Nov-2016 00:00:00.000' and '01-Dec-2016 99:99:99.999' or wdatetime between '01-Nov-2016 00:00:00.000' and '01-Dec-2016 99:99:99.999'
```

following is the front end query code

```
    Public DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT As String = "dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" 
DAILYREPORTQRY = "select * from WEIGHT where Odate between '" & fromDate.Value.ToString(DEFAULT_REPORT_DATE_FORMAT) & " 00:00:00.000' and '" & toDate.Value.ToString(DEFAULT_REPORT_DATE_FORMAT) & " 99:99:99.999' or wdatetime between '" & fromDate.Value.ToString(DEFAULT_REPORT_DATE_FORMAT) & " 00:00:00.000' and '" & toDate.Value.ToString(DEFAULT_REPORT_DATE_FORMAT) & " 99:99:99.999'"
```

I've used two Date time pickers to select the date with Custom Format as 'dd/MMM/yyyy' it displays the date in format which I want but if the system date format changes it changes itself, so whats the point of having custom format.

So basically 2 major questions are as follow,

1) How to query through records with date format as in stored in DB
2) How to hard code the format for Front end application to search by the default format without taking care of system date format.

Please advice I've 5000 records which need to be taken care.

Thank you.

Comment: Why you save date and time as varchar!

Comment: You need to change the data type to `datetime`. If you want to store a date or datetime, use the correct datatype. Don't ever use a varchar. Use this query to confirm that the data can be converted to a date: `SELECT Odate, CONVERT(DATETIME,REPLACE(LEFT(ODate,20),'/',' '), 113) FROM WEIGHT`

Comment: You could also add parameter to you SQL Command and specify the parameters as DataTime.  This is usually the prefer method. See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: Also fix the query to use parameters instead of concatenation. Not only do you avoid a SQL injection attack, you also avoid conversion errors like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dates you need use correct `data-type`, in this case `DateTime` . So you can compare values in the same format, and you handle with datetime in easy way.

To convert that dates (in wrong type) to datetime you can see this link: [how to convert nvarchar to datetime datatype](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/47fc07d2-37fe-4dd8-b57f-3867cd57e2b0/how-to-convert-nvarchar-to-datetime-datatype?forum=transactsql)

Try use `CONVERT`, for example try with:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '23 Oct 2016 11:02:07:577', 113)
```

you convert: 23 Oct 2016 11:02:07:577 to 2016-10-23 11:02:07.577

and here you have differents format to convert: [how to convert format](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/)

Hope this help!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14771868)

Comment: @CalebKleveter: is ok now?